# How can I handle a specific IOException?

Tags: c#, serial-port, ioexception

I have a code that uses Socket and SerialPort and I'd like to handle specific exceptions. With Socket I don't have problems, because the SocketException class has SocketErrorCode and I use it in a switch to handle the errors, but I don't find something similar for the IOException class.

Is there a list of exceptions for the IOException class?

```
try
{
    strTemp = "Command";
    fnWriteCommand(strTemp, communicationInterface);
    index = 10;
}
catch (SocketException socketEx)
{
    switch (socketEx.SocketErrorCode)
    {
        case SocketError.ConnectionRefused:
        case SocketError.ConnectionAborted:
        case SocketError.ConnectionReset:
        case SocketError.NotConnected:
            index = 0; // Restart sequence
            break;
        case SocketError.TimedOut:
            index = 10; // Retry
            break;
    }
}
catch (IOException IOEx)
{
    // Handle specific exceptions
}
```

Comment: impossible to tell without the knowledge of what is called and potentially throwing in `fnWriteCommand`. there are seven subclasses of `IOException`, which you could catch specifically, or check `IOEx` against: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ioexception?view=netframework-4.7.2 then there is `IOEx.HResult`.

Comment: I am sending commands trought SerialPort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class uses an internal wrapper around the low-level port communication functions of the operating system, [System.IO.Ports.InternalResources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/io/ports/InternalResources.cs,f174d63c327698c8).

This module deals with the I/O errors and converts them into a managed `System.IO.IOException`. Unfortunately, some of them do not use a numeric error code, only a text which is subject to translation (resource identifier and en-us translation):

```
IO_PortNotFound "The specified port does not exist."
IO_PortNotFoundFileName "The port '{0}' does not exist."
IO_SharingViolation_NoFileName "The process cannot access the port because it is being used by another process."
IO_SharingViolation_File "The process cannot access the port '{0}' because it is being used by another process."
```

All Winapi HREsult codes that are not mapped to any of those four exception strings, are converted into an `IOException` using the `HResult` and text that the Windows API provides via the `FormatMessage` API.

From the many subclasses of `IOException`, only `EndOfStreamException` is used in the serialport context, and can be specifically catched, or queried like this:

```
if(IOEx is EndOfStreamException) 
{
    var eosex = IOEx as EndOfStreamException;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `IOException` class has several derived exceptions that get thrown that give more information about the IO error that was encountered. You can catch these individually:

```
try { // Some code }
catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException) { }
catch (System.IO.DriveNotFoundException) { }
catch (System.IO.EndOfStreamException) { }
catch (System.IO.FileLoadException) { }
catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException) { }
catch (System.IO.InternalBufferOverflowException) { }
catch (System.IO.InvalidDataException) { }
catch (System.IO.PathTooLongException) { }
catch (System.IO.IOException) { // Something else happened. Check InnerException details }
```